# привязать функцию к кнопке

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, matplotlib

у меня есть одна задача:
я строю график-поверхности с помощью библиотеки matplotlib. Мне необходимо создать графический интерфейс для ввода функции и построения графика, но пока что не могу привязать эти функции к кнопкам.
вот что имею:

```
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy

from tkinter import*
from math import*

#создание окна
root=Tk()
root.geometry('600x320')
canvas=Canvas(root, width=1040, height=640, bg='#012')
canvas.pack(side='right')

#создание поля ввода
label_f=Label(root, text='Введите функцию вида Z=(X,Y):', font='Arial 18')
label_f.place(x=10, y=20)
entry_f=Entry(root, width=25, bd=6)
entry_f.place(x=380,y=25)


#создание кнопки удалить
btn_calc=Button(root, text='Удалить',font='Arial 15', bg='#996',fg='white')
btn_calc.bind('<Button-1>')
btn_calc.place(x=270,y=150)

#создание кнопки построить график
btn_calc2=Button(root, text='Построить поверхность',font='Arial 15', bg='#996',fg='white')
btn_calc2.bind('<Button-1>')
btn_calc2.place(x=200,y=100)
root.mainloop()
#ввод данных для поверхности

def makeData():
    x = numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)
    y = numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)
    x, y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)

    z = numpy.sin(x * 0.3) * numpy.cos(y * 0.75)
    return x, y, z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, y, z = makeData()

#построение поверхности
    fig = pylab.figure()
    axes = Axes3D(fig)
    axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
    pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, надо во второй аргумент к методу bind записать имя функции, которая при нажатии мышкой на кнопку должна выполняться без параметров:

```
Name_Of_Your_Button.bind('<Button-1>', Name_Of_Your_Function)#В конце функции не пиши скобок
```